# Problems with Windows phone browser

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml, windows-phone-8, webbrowser-control

I have created a windows phone browser but instead of adding it via xaml I decided to add it via c#.

In this xaml I added a grid

```
 <Grid Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Name="browserHost"/>
```

and added a browser to the grid via c#

```
browserHost.Children.Add(browser);
```

So my question is what code should I use to access the browser in c# and is there anyway I could use this in a navigated event?

For example if I was to modify the width how would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the width, simply:

```
browser.Width = 400;
```

To hook an event:

```
browser.Navigated += (s,e) => { do something};
```